# How can I rank the total number of calls taken by a rep for each date in Power Bi/DAX?

Tags: powerbi, dax

I'm looking to create rankings that answer this goal:

- For each Date, rank number of calls taken from highest to lowest per rep
- Maintain this ranking for each date, regardless of how many dates are included

What I want to end up with:

| Name | Date | Total Calls | Rank |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Rep A | 11/10/2020 | 27 | 3 |
| Rep B | 11/10/2020 | 28 | 2 |
| Rep C | 11/10/2020 | 29 | 1 |
| Rep A | 11/11/2020 | 27 | 3 |
| Rep B | 11/11/2020 | 28 | 2 |
| Rep C | 11/11/2020 | 29 | 1 |

I've found enough information on how to rank across all dates, but I can't figure out how to rank in the row context of each specific date. Any help would be appreciated!

Update:

I followed the instructions below which were really helpful, but came up with this ranking where total calls are not in order:

[Ranking Not in Order of Most Calls](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MnIGF.png)

Here is the DAX as I have it:

```
Call Rank = 

IF (  
ISINSCOPE ( Final[Name] ),  
CALCULATE (  
    RANKX (  
        ALL ( Final[Name] ),  
        CALCULATE (  
            SUM ( Final[Total Calls] )  
        )  
    ),  
    ALLEXCEPT (  
        Final,  
        Final[Data Period],  
        Final[Name]  
    )  
)  
)
```

Comment: In your report I see a "Date" column, but in your measure you are referring to Final[Date Period]. Are you using a Date table? can you please share a sample of your model reproducing the behavior you are experiencing, without showing sensible data?

Comment: Hey Sergiom, 
That Fixed it! I updated where it says "Final[Data Period]" to refer to my Calendar table and date column "'Date'[Date]". Thank you so much for the help.

Comment: glad It worked :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your input table is `Calls`, taken from your table

[image: Calls table]

We can define a measure to compute per each day the ranking of `Name` per number of calls

```
RankPerDay =
IF (
    ISINSCOPE ( Calls[Name] ),
    CALCULATE (
        RANKX (
            ALL ( Calls[Name] ),
            CALCULATE (
                SUM ( Calls[Total Calls] )
            )
        ),
        ALLEXCEPT (
            Calls,
            Calls[Date],
            Calls[Name]
        )
    )
)
```

Fist we check if the measure is evaluated at the Name level of granularity, otherwise we return BLANK(). Then, we use `CALCULATE` and `ALLEXCEPT` to remove any existing filter context keeping only the one over `Name` and the one over `Date`. With this modified filter context, we call `RANKX` specifying to build a ranking table containing all Names and the total minute calls per Date and Name, in order to retrieve the current Name ranking.

This is the resulting matrix visual with `Calls[Date]` and `Calls[Name]` on the rows

[image: matrix visual]

Comment: here is the dax guide about RANKX https://dax.guide/rankx/

Comment: Hey Sergiom,
Thank you for the help! I edited my question as the rank order doesn't seem to be correct, so I'm not sure where I made an error.

Comment: As input I used the table you provided in your question. I'm afraid that the real model you have is different. Can you provide some sample data matching the real model?

Comment: Link to some of the data:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1X1OyXYRiKUn7Nf7pM8kA_ud6v_lyI9kFYYstak7D50g/edit?usp=sharing 
There are a number of other variables on the table (chats, length of calls, time on chats, etc.) but I wasn't sure if that was relevant, so this is the dates for two days, total calls, and names, last names redacted.

Comment: To make sure others saw this, I had to change my date reference in the DAX expression to refer to the Calendar table I was using. Thanks!